# x86 assembly compare operator

Tags: c, assembly, switch-statement, x86-64, reverse-engineering

I'm new to learning assembly. I have an assignment to reverse engineer a switch statement into C. I am a bit stuck on this part which to me, seems to be a conditional. The variable n is passed into rsi. My question is, when the operation n-50 is done, does that value stay in rsi for the compare operation directly below that? or does rsi get reset? **note .L7 is the start of the jump table.

```
subq $50, %rsi
cmpq $5, %rsi
ja .L2
jmp *.L7(,%rsi,8)

//jump table 
L7:
.quad .L3
.quad .L2
.quad .L3
.quad .L4
.quad .L5
.quad .L6
.text
```

should my C code look something like this?

```
result = n - 50; 
if result == 5
   GOTO .L2
else 
   GOTO .L7
```

OR since .ja means jump if above, should it be

```
  result = n - 50; 
    if result > 5
       GOTO .L2
    else 
       GOTO .L7
```

this is the full assembly code

```
.file "switch_prob-soln.c"
.text
.globl switch_prob
.type switch_prob, @function
switch_prob:
.LFB0:
.cfi_startproc
subq $50, %rsi
cmpq $5, %rsi
ja .L2
jmp *.L7(,%rsi,8)
.section .rodata
.align 8
.align 4
.L7:
.quad .L3 
.quad .L2
.quad .L3
.quad .L4
.quad .L5
.quad .L6  
.text
.L3:
leaq 0(,%rdi,4), %rax
ret
.L4:
movq %rdi, %rax
sarq $2, %rax
ret
.L5:
leaq (%rdi,%rdi,2), %rdi
.L6:
imulq %rdi, %rdi
.L2:
leaq 10(%rdi), %rax
ret
.cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
.size switch_prob, .-switch_prob
```

Comment: Yes of course the result stays in `rsi`. Yes `ja` is `jump if above`, so `result > 5`. Also that's an unsigned comparison so automatically excludes negative numbers too. Obviously as you said it should be a `switch` statement. The listed labels are the cases for `0`..`5`.

Comment: Trivia: `cmp $5, %rsi` inside CPU does execute subtraction too: `rsi-5`, but the result is then discarded (`rsi` keeps it's value), only flag register is updated in the same way, as `rsi-5` would update it. Your `GOTO .L7` is wrong (as Jester notes by "switch"), It's `GOTO .L7[rsi]` in C (`.L7` is array of QWORDs). And that should give you enough info to write it as switch ... case 0/1/2../5.

Comment: The C code should look like a switch statement, nothing more, nothing less. The subtraction, comparison, and jump table are all hints that tell you which values are supported as `case` statements.

Comment: @user3386109 so the if else isn't necessary then for my program? everything before the jump table is essentially just there to tell the machine what values are for the case statements? (note: i put the rest of the assembly in)

Comment: Correct, the if/else is not part of the answer. The subtract/compare/jump is used to make sure that the value is within the range supported by the jump table. I would assume that `L2` is the `default` case, which handles any values that aren't part of the jump table.